# TimeMachine backup shared network drive not listed under "select disk"

Tags: network, time-machine, macos

I will use a shared network drive for TimeMachine backup. I can mount the drive via the Finder: `Network -> MachineA -> Drive0`. Get Info shows the drive is mounted as: `afp://MachineA._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Drive0`. This is the same way a second drive (call it `Drive1`) is mounted from a second mac server (call it `MachineB`). When I attempt to select `Drive0` as the TimeMachine disk, it is not listed as an option, but `Drive1` is! Incidentally, `MachineA` is currently using `Drive0` as a TimeMachine backup disk. Call the client (to-be-backed-up) computer, `MachineC`.

What is required of a drive *from a networking perspective* for it to be listed as an option when "Select Backup Disk" is invoked? In other words, what do I need to check/ensure about the connection between `MachineC` and `MachineA` such that `Drive0` is mounted/discovered in such a way that it will be listed as an option for selection in the TimeMachine preference pane?

(`MachineA`, 10.11; `MachineB`, 10.13; `MachineC`, 10.12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem results from this detail: `MachineA` is currently using `Drive0` as a TimeMachine backup disk.

> Note that the TimeMachine backup volume is "read-only" only for everyone user, but "read&write" for system and wheel users. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8216189

Thus, `Disk0` was being shared as read only and hence the problem.

Looks like there is a fix for this in 10.13, a location can be shared as a TimeMachine backup destination:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202784

http://www.nandakusumadi.com/blog/2017/12/10/how-to-setup-shared-time-machine-drive